# USB connected devices info

Tags: ubuntu, usb-drive

In my project, I need a list with all connected usb drives and some data about(name, format, size, label, if it is mounted or not, where is mounted)
All this data is parsed by a php script then stored into a database;

So far, I'm using `blkid -c /dev/null` to get drive location and format; then, using this script found online, I check if it is mounted or not;

```
#!/bin/bash
cat /etc/mtab | grep $1 >/dev/null
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
echo 1
else
echo 0
fi
```

I googled about getting more info about a drive and found a lot of tools; still, I was wondering if there is a tool that will return just the info I need, without doing a lot of parsing;

Apache will run as "www-data" but this user will get access to required commands; no need to talk about security because this pc is used just by me(local network);

Comment: You can use `sudo fdisk -l` & `df -h -T` , `lsusb`

Comment: You could use `lsblk`, e.g. `lsblk -lo name,tran,size,type,fstype,mountpoint`. Run `lsblk --help` to see available output options.